# Angular 6 display sanitized background image

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I've been able to construct the image url without receiving the sanitizer errors, but my background image still will not show up. Do I have to access the "changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity" property for this image to show properly? Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image: Chrome DevTools]

**UPDATE:**
It seems wrong to access this property in the markup, but it works.
[image]

Comment: After running into this same issue a year later, I have found a better solution based on @Andriy solution below.
 
Use: "SecurityContext.URL" instead of "SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL"
 
this.userProfilePhoto = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.URL, `${ this.userDetails.profilePhotoUrl }?t=${ this.timestamp }`);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the actual property `changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity` since you need to get the url string.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a row resouce URL of `safeValue` object, [`DomSanitizerImpl.sanitize()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.0.0/packages/platform-browser/src/security/dom_sanitization_service.ts#L151) function may be used:

```
...
import { ɵDomSanitizerImpl, DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

// row URL 
url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ea793dcbaff5a5e29ad3d05ef564d86';

// safe value type URL
safeUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);

// sanitized back from safe value raw URL
sanitizedUrl = this._sanitizerImpl.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.safeUrl);

...
constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, protected _sanitizerImpl: ɵDomSanitizerImpl) {}
```

I created a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkg7gx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to demonstrate it, please look at `console.logs`